# Newton's "Famous Blunder"?

Tags: calculus, math-history, infinitesimals

On page $225$ of *Isaac Newton on Mathematical Certainty and Method* by Niccolo Guicciardini (see [here for a link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262516489)), I read

> In the following demonstration... Newton made a famous blunder... He wrote, "Case 1. Any rectangle as $AB$ increased by a continual motion, when the halves of the moments ${1\over 2}a$ and ${1\over 2}b$, were lacking from the sides $A$ and $B$, was $A-{1\over 2}a$ multiplied by $B-{1\over 2}b$, or $AB-{1\over 2}aB-{1\over 2}bA+{1\over 4}ab$, and as soon as the sides $A$ and $B$ have been increased by the other halves of the moments; it comes out $A+{1\over 2}a$ multiplied by $B+{1\over 2}b$, or $AB+{1\over 2}aB+{1\over 2}bA+{1\over 4}ab$. Subtract the former rectangle from this rectangle, and there will remain the excess $aB+bA$. Therefore by the total increments $a$ and $b$ of the sides, there is generated the increment $aB+bA$ of the rectangle. *Q.E.D.*"

This reasoning seems perfectly fine to me $-$ what is the "momentous mistake"?

Comment: @MikeMiller, Newton shows that $(A+a/2)(B+b/2)-(A-a/2)(B-b/2)=aB+bA$, which is evident from mentioning both "lacking" and "increased" cases.

Comment: Is it possible to have a statement of the fact he was trying to prove?  It could be that his mistake was not in that particular case, but rather in the linking of the case to his proposition.

Comment: @Michael You're right. Stupid mistake, thanks.

Comment: @anorton The lemma is a general rule to the effect that $$\frac{d}{dx}A^{m}B^{n}C^{l}\cdots = maA^{m-1}BC\cdots+\,nbB^{n-1}AC\cdots+\,lcC^{l-1}AB\cdots+\ldots$$ (in other words, the product rule + power rule, and a sort of basic chain rule as well) where $a=A'$, $b=B'$, etc. Guicciardini says that because the proofs of cases $2$-$6$ [of the lemma] are based on the "faulty demonstration of Case 1, Newton's [proof] cannot be said to have been satisfactory."

Comment: Dumb question: Are $A$ and $B$ (etc.) matrices?

Comment: (Possibly silly question) Does the final sentence mean: $(A+a)(B+b)=AB+aB+Ba+ab?$

Comment: @anorton No, they are generic functions (i.e. numbers) that depend on time (or some independent variable), although Newton didn't think of them quite like that. By the "rectangle $AB$" Newton just means "the number $A\times B$". And no such thing as a dumb question!

Comment: @chubakueno Not sure about the final sentence, but yes that rule is used several times. And no such thing as a possibly silly question!

Comment: Oh, I was asking because maybe I misunderstood it(I'm not really a fan of verbose ultra-old-school mathematics, and english is not my native language). I was saying that maybe the error was that in the last sentence Newton thought he proved $(A+a)(B+b)=AB+aB+Ba$(without the $ab$)

Comment: It seems to me that, reading the "convoluted" explanation preceeding the **Lemma II** we can try to understand N's approach; we can interpret it as saying that the product of a (finite) magnitude (as $A$ and $B$) times a "moment" (i.e.a momentaneous increment or decrement : $a$ and $b$) is a quantity **but** the product of two moments is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about my "interpretation" of the above discussion, but I'll try with a "long comment".

Newton did not make an "algebraic" mistake.

We have :

> $(A+a/2)(B+b/2) = AB + aB/2 + bA/2 + ab/4$

and :

> $(A−a/2)(B−b/2) = AB - aB/2 - bA/2 + ab/4$;

thus :

> > $(A+a/2)(B+b/2) - (A−a/2)(B−b/2) = aB + bA$.

The problem arouse in the "geometrical" interpretation [*sorry, but I'm not able to draw the figures* ...].

*(i)* If you draw the rectangle $A \times B$ **inside** the rectangle $(A + a) \times (B + b)$, you will have that the area of the difference between the two (the so-called *gnomon*) will be :

> $(A + a)(B + b) - AB = aB + bA + ab$.

Thus, in this case, it is **not** true that the "total increments $a$ and $b$ of the sides [have] generated the increment $aB+bA$ of the rectangle".

*(ii)* **But** Newton did it differently.

He draw **three** rectangles: $A \times B$ with **outside** it the rectangle $(A + a/2) \times (B + b/2)$ and **inside** it the rectangle $(A - a/2) \times (B - b/2)$.

Now, if we compute the *gnomon* described by the "outer" one and the "inner" one, we have that :

> > $(A+a/2)(B+b/2) - (A−a/2)(B−b/2) = aB + bA$;

I mean that we can check it "geometrically" and not only algebraically.

This is Newton's "trick": to "prove" geometrically that the term $ab$ can be discarded. He has been able to make "disappear" the unwanted second-order "infinitesimal". Of course, the key of the proof lay in its "interpretation" ...

We have to remember that he does **not** speak of "infinitesimal", *contra* Leibniz; at the same time, N's "foundations" of its *fluxional* calculus are at least "debatable" (like Leibniz's one), and they were debated.

See in this regard [Jacob Walton](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/ref%3aodnb/53925)'s pamphlets in response to George Berkeley's [The Analyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst) (1734); in [A Vindication of Sir Isaac Newton [...]](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Walton/Vindication/) (1735) there is a long and convoluted discussion trying to justify N's proof.

See also Carl Boyer, [The History of the Calculus and Its Conceptual Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486605094) (1949 - Dover reprint), pages 198-199, for comments on N's proof.

Answer (score 1):

> This reasoning seems perfectly fine to me − what is the "momentous mistake"?

Ideally, Guicciardini would have elaborated on that, then I wouldn't need to guess.

If the purpose of the section is to establish the differentiability of a product of differentiable functions and the product rule, then Newton's argument has the problem that he computes (more or less)

$$\frac{A\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right)B\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right) - A\left(x-\frac{h}{2}\right)B\left(x-\frac{h}{2}\right)}{h},$$

and as we all know, the existence of

$$\lim_{h\downarrow 0} \frac{F\left(x+\frac{h}{2}\right) - F\left(x-\frac{h}{2}\right)}{h}$$

does not imply the differentiability of $F$ in $x$.

If the differentiability of the product is assumed or proven in a different way, the argument is correct to find the product rule.